# Overclocking the AMD Sempron 3100+?

Tags: overclocking

I know it is possible to overclock the processor, but I need help finding software capable. As it has no features in bios to do so. AMD Overdrive did not work for overclocking. Any ideas?

Machine: eMachines w3107

Operating System: Windows 8.1 Home

Comment: Try using AMD's official software for that: http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/technologies-gaming/over-drive

Comment: What BIOS are you using ? Almost any BIOS should be able to let you select FSB frequency.

Comment: I only know that it is a Phoenix bios, and that I did use AMD Overdrive (the official version), but my computer is too old to be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using setFSB http://www13.plala.or.jp/setfsb/ but be careful when selecing the clock generator. Although your specific model is not listed, some motherboards and processor share the same chipset and may have the same or similar clock generator. Since this is a software overclock, if you freeze, just restart your machine and you should be back to normal frequency.

However, each time you fail, you risk losing data or smoking your motherboard. When testing, increase clock frequency by a very small increment and check for stability. Keep CPUz open to monitor actual frequencies.

Good luck!

Comment: Worked, but I found another way with ClockGen. Note that software overclocking is never a great idea, but I needed to go that route as my BIOS didn't have the features for overclocking.